# SASS- apply CSS if attribute selector not present

Tags: html, css, sass, less

I've an HTML & CSS

```css
[class^="layout-"] div, [class*=" layout-"] div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.layout-20X80 div.label-txt {
  width: 20%
}

.layout-20X80 div.value-container {
  width: 80%
}
```

```html
<div class="dync-template tmp-bg layout-20X80">
  <div class="label-txt">Select Your Response</div>
    <div class="value-container">
      <p>Hello World!!</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've multiple classes `.layout-20X80, .layout-30X70, .layout-40X60` etc.I basically want to apply `width:100%` to `label-txt, .value-container` if this attribute selector`(layout-)` is not present in parent div

Comment: Have you looked into CSS :not?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes I got the answer with :not

Answer (score 1):

We can use `:not`

```css
div.dync-template:not([class^="layout-"], [class*=" layout-"]) {
   div.label-txt {
        max-width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        line-height: 1.25px;
        margin-bottom: 0.50rem; 
        padding: 8px 0px;
    }
    div.value-container {
        max-width:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="dync-template tmp-bg layout-20X80">
  <div class="label-txt">Select Your Response</div>
    <div class="value-container">
      <p>Hello World!!</p>
   </div>
</div>
```